# Rails 5 UJS: How to specify a single js file for execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have multiple actions that use the same js.

```
def say_hello
 puts 'hello'
 respond_to :js
end

def say_hi
 puts 'hi'
 respond_to :js
end

#hello.js.erb
toast.success('Success!')

#hi.js.erb
toast.success('Success!')
```

How can I specify all actions to run one js.erb file after execution?

```
#universal.js.erb
toast.success('Success!')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify which view to render in your controller method.

controller

```
def say_hello
  puts 'hello'
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'universal' }
  end
end

def say_hi
  puts 'hi'
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'universal' }
  end
end
```

view

```
#universal.js.erb
toast.success('Success!')
```